# readlink: error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm trying to build kernel 5.15 using clang version 18, when i try to initialise the build using `BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.aarch64 build/build.sh` it then returns an error

```
readlink: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto-host.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

though on checking if libcrypto-host.so exists `locate libcrypto-host.so` then the result

```
/home/kali/Desktop/kern/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/asan/lib64/libcrypto-host.so
/home/kali/Desktop/kern/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/lib64/libcrypto-host.so
/home/kali/Desktop/kern/prebuilts/build-tools/linux_musl-x86/asan/lib64/libcrypto-host.so
/home/kali/Desktop/kern/prebuilts/build-tools/linux_musl-x86/lib64/libcrypto-host.so
/home/kali/Desktop/kern/prebuilts/kernel-build-tools/linux-x86/lib64/libcrypto-host.so
```

adding these directories to path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then the error still occurs, what is the issue on this.

running all these on a virtual box. My working directory is `Desktop/kern/`